# Date object in Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I have a cucumber stepdef like this

```
Given the date of <date>
When blah blah
Then x y and z
Examples:
|2015-01-01|
|2045-01-01|
```

When I generate stepdefs off of this, I get `@Given("^the date of (\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)$")`
And the method is generated with three integers as parameters.
How can I tell Cucumber to treat it like a Java.Time LocalDate? Is there a way to create a mapper that Cucumber will understand? Or at the very least, is there a way to treat that date object as a string instead of three numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Cucumber 7, I'm defining a new `@ParameterType` :

```
@ParameterType("\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}")
public LocalDate mydate(String dateString) {
    return LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
}
```

Then I can use step definition `@Given` such as :

```
@Given("person has birthdate {mydate}")
public void person_birthdate(LocalDate birthDate) {
    ... // do something
}
```

The placeholder name `{mydate}` is the name of the mapping method, but you can override it through `@ParameterType.name`.

Answer (score 9):

Modify your step definition to take in a String for the whole date. Maybe use something like (.*?) instead of 3 integers.

```
@Given("^the date of (.*?)$")
public void storeDate(@Transform(DateMapper.class) LocalDate date){

}
```

Transformer class

```
public class DateMapper extends Transformer<LocalDate>{

    @Override
    public LocalDate transform(String date) {

        //Not too sure about the date pattern though, check it out if it gives correct result
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

        return LocalDate.parse(date, formatter); 
   }

}
```

Cucumber should transform the string format into a date object for you

Comment: i am still getting @Given("^the date of (\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)$") And the method is generated with three integers as parameters. How can I tell Cucumber to trea error

Comment: You are using the default method stepdef pattern and arguments generated by cucumber. Edit it to the string pattern and argument you want to get data into the method.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if this works -

```
Scenario Outline: Date  
Given the date of <date>
When blah blah
Then x y and z
Examples:
|date      |
|2015-01-01|
|2045-01-01|
```

I have modified the default step definition like this -

```
@Given("^the date of (.*?)$")
public void the_date_of(String strDate) throws Throwable {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = format.parse(strDate);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

This prints the code like this -

```
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 AEDT 2015
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 AEDT 2045
```

Comment: still gets @Given("^the date of (\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)$") And the method is generated with three integers as parameters. How can I tell Cucumber to trea error