# Why does IDE II not see a custom registered parameter for the cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber

https://github.com/aleks70694/cucumberStudy
The following error occurs when trying to start the runner:

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not create a cucumber expression for 'передадим в метод дату {localdate}'.
It appears you did not register a parameter type.
```

Realize step:

```
    @Given("передадим в метод дату {localdate}")
    public void inMethodDate(LocalDate localdate) {
        System.out.println(localdate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));
    }
```

RunTest.java

```
package myStudy.runner;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
        glue = {"myStudy/stepDefinitions", "myStudy/typeRegistry"},
        features = "src/test/resources/features"
)
public class RunTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

TypeRegistryConfiguration.java
Path: src/test/java/myStudy/typeRegistry/typeRegistryConfigurer.java

```
package myStudy.typeRegistry;

import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistry;
import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistryConfigurer;
import io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.ParameterType;
import io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.Transformer;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class TypeRegistryConfiguration implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {
    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
// требуется только для определения формата разделителя в float и double
        return new Locale("ru");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
// добавление в реестр определения необходимого типа
        typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
// название параметра, используемое в определении шага:
                "localdate",
// регулярка, для поиска необходимого значения в фиче:
                "[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}",
// тип параметра:
                LocalDate.class,
// функция, преобразующая входящую строку к нужному типу
                (Transformer<LocalDate>) s -> {
                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
                    return LocalDate.parse(s, formatter);
                }
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40164099/16416581. So you may need to add @Transform annotation

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning Cucumber consider [starting with a more recent version](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/). Then parameter types can be declared more elegantly:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/java#parameter-type

```
package com.example.app;

import io.cucumber.java.ParameterType;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @ParameterType("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})")
    public LocalDate iso8601Date(String year, String month, String day) {
        return LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));
    }

    @Given("today is {iso8601Date}")
    public void today_is(LocalDate date) {

    }
}
```